# Magento 2: header.panel Block Missing

Tags: magento2, blocks, header

I have move my Magento 2 website from shared host to VPS. I just finished moving site and it is loading fine. For some reason `header.panel` block is now missing in the header of site?

I have compared new site to backup of old site and there are no differences in any files. I can not work out why it is no longer displaying.

I have tried recompiling the site but no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas why it would now not be being displayed?

Comment: Have you cleared the var/generation and var/view_preprocessed folders? How did you do the migration? If it was through git, you could have had a file change that didn't make it over. Are you sure that the block itself is not rendering and it isn't an issue with a static block not showing that hasn't been migrated?

Comment: Hi, yes cleared all of those - still no luck. All files where copied over via ftp and I have used to beyond compare to compare them from the old site to the new location and there are no file differences. The static blocks are fine becuase if I move them to another block they display fine it is just the header.panel not being rendered and I have search all the code and there is no remove on that particualr block either?

Answer (score 0):

Given all the things you have verified to be correct, take a look in the DB at the `theme` table and check to see if the `type` is set to 1 or 0. If the theme you are using is set to 1, some xml files (for some unknown reason to me) will not be loaded.